Automation for Open layers WMS and WFS calls
Is it possible to automate OpenLayers WMS and WFS calls?
Which tool is required to use?
While loading layers then it will call WFS or WMS, so how to check there is WFS or WMS call getting successful response using automation scripts/tool.
e.g. We have multiple layers in the menu and while user checks particular layer then only that layer visible on map.
So, we have to do automated while we do test or sanity, so we don't require to click on each and every check box to load layer or call WMS or WFS call.
Automatically through the automation script required to load each and every layer with WFS/WMS calls with check their success call or not.

You could use WFS/WMS GetCapabilities request to check availability of the service.

Hi TomazicM, May you please provide some examples to how we can implement. So it will be helpful us.
